# I want to correlate multiple column from different DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Given:

result

```
| D001 | D002 | D003 | D004 | D005 |
|------|------|------|------|------|
| 3    | 5    | 3    | 4    | 4    |
| 4    | 4    | 5    | 3    | 4    |
| 5    | 4    | 5    | 5    | 3    |
```

individual

```
| Engagement Index | Manager Index | HR Index | Manager Index |
|------------------|---------------|----------|---------------|
| 3.14             | 3.78          | 4.88     | 4.21          |
| 4.15             | 4.27          | 2.89     | 4.43          |
| 4.20             | 3.89          | 3.92     | 4.65          |
```

I have two DataFrame `result` and `individual`. From which I want to correlated between result[corr_col]  and individual[corr_with] column.

`corr_col = ['D001', 'D002', 'D003', 'D004', 'D005', 'D006', 'D007', 'D008']`

`corr_with = ['Engagement Index','Manager Index','HR Index','Leadership Index']`

I tried

```
for j in corr_with:
    val = []
    for i in corr_col:
        x = round(result[i].corr(individual[j]),2)
        val.append(x)

    correlation = pd.DataFrame({'Driver': corr_col, j : val})
correlation
```

But this gives me

```
| Driver | Leadership Index | 
|--------|------------------|
| D001   | 0.72             |
| D002   | 0.78             | 
| D003   | 0.75             | 
| D004   | 0.71             | 
| D005   | 0.73             | 
| D006   | 0.74             | 
| D007   | 0.76             | 
| D008   | 0.38             |
```

I had even tried

`result[corr_col].corr(individual[corr_with])`
which gives me ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

**Required Output:**

```
| Driver | Engagement Index | Manager Index | HR Index | Leadership Index |
|--------|------------------|---------------|----------|------------------|
| D001   | 0.72             | 0.64          | 0.81     | 0.67             |
| D002   | 0.78             | 0.75          | 0.80     | 0.70             |
| D003   | 0.75             | 0.69          | 0.78     | 0.69             |
| D004   | 0.71             | 0.72          | 0.73     | 0.74             |
| D005   | 0.73             | 0.71          | 0.75     | 0.76             |
| D006   | 0.74             | 0.78          | 0.68     | 0.68             |
| D007   | 0.76             | 0.78          | 0.75     | 0.80             |
| D008   | 0.38             | 0.75          | 0.69     | 0.78             |
```

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: show your input data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think here is necessary assign each list in nested loop to final list `out` and pass it to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
out = []
for j in corr_with:
    val = []
    for i in corr_col:
        x = round(result[i].corr(individual[j]),2)
        val.append(x)
    out.append(val)
```

Or list comprehension solution:

```
out = [[round(result[i].corr(individual[j]),2) for i in corr_col] for j in corr_with]
```

---

```
correlation = pd.DataFrame(out, index=corr_with, columns=corr_col).T
```

Another solution with [`DataFrame.corrwith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corrwith.html):

```
correlation = pd.concat([result.corrwith(individual[x]).round(2) for x in corr_with], 
                         axis=1, 
                         keys=corr_with)
```